# Chrome extension permission for "about:blank" page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension is not using `content_scripts` because I do not want to inject the code into every page. Instead, when the user clicks on the button a popup window opens and injects code into the page.

So, in the `manifest.json` there is a permissions block:

```
"permissions": [
  "activeTab"
]
```

And in the `popup.js` there is this code:

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent( function(win) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        'windowId': win.id,
        'active': true
    }, function(tabArray) {

        // inject css & js only on initial click
        chrome.tabs.executeScript( null, {
            code : 'document.querySelector( "body" ).classList.contains( "_myExtension_code_injected" )'
        }, function( result ) {
            if ( result && !result[0] ) {
                chrome.tabs.insertCSS( null, {
                    file: 'myExtension.css'
                });

                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                    file: 'myExtension.js'
                }, function(){
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                        code: 'myExtension.init();'
                    });
                });
            }
        });

    });
});
```

The problem is some web sites open a popup window with additional information. And the URL of that popup page is `"about:blank"`. If I try to initialize the extension, I see this message in the console:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "about:blank". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

I do not see a way to add a `"about:blank"` page to the `permissions`. And I really don't want to start using `content_scripts` just so I can set the `match_about_blank` setting.

I've tried adding `"about:blank"` and `"about:*` to the `permission` and all I get is an installation error.

> There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
>   Permission 'about:*' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.

Is there a solution?

---

Update: [Here is a gist with everything you'll need](https://gist.github.com/Mottie/91968692d074f93eb9a7). A link to a jsbin demo included, but the problem isn't with that site specifically. The extension was originally tested on a yahoo mail pop-out window which you get by choosing to print an email.

Comment: Can't you just check the `windows.location.href` value against `about:blank` before executing any code?

Comment: Chrome is preventing the code injection because it needs permission. I included the error it shows above.

Comment: I understand that part. But what I meant was to put the check around the inject part, if possible. (I don't know enough of this to be sure if possible)

Comment: That won't work, the error is from executing `chrome.tabs.executeScript` which is the same function that injects the javascript.

Comment: @Daniel_L I tried removing the injection code in the popup.js & adding a `content_scripts` section to the manifest, but it still doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Could you give an example of a page (or a video) that shows the problem? A Chrome extension can only execute a script on `about:blank` when the frame's origin can be determined, *and* the extension has the permission to run scripts on that origin. So if it is an `about:blank` page without opener window or parent frame that is accessible by your extension, then the extension will be denied access.

Comment: @RobW I created this gist with all the files & instructions to duplicate the issue: https://gist.github.com/Mottie/91968692d074f93eb9a7 I would appreciate any help! :D

Comment: @Mottie I got stuck at "In Chrome, right click on the header & use "Show as Tab"". There is no such option for me. But when you get such a tab, what do you see if you type `window.opener` in the console? And what about `document.origin`?

Comment: I added a [screenshot](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/136959/9567374/1768aa66-4eee-11e5-8cb5-e8bf4bff744b.png) to the gist. In this case `window.opener` is defined but `document.origin` points to `"http://null.jsbin.com"`. The problem isn't with jsbin specifically, I was originally testing it in Yahoo mail with the print popout window.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: The bug is still open - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=466422

Answer (score 6):

Try using `chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: "script.js", matchAboutBlank: true })`

"If matchAboutBlank is true, then the code is also injected in about:blank and about:srcdoc frames if your extension has access to its parent document. Code cannot be inserted in top-level about:-frames. By default it is false."

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-details-matchAboutBlank

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed that in the documentation. Sadly, even after adding that parameter, I am still seeing the same error message.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that the "about:blank" popup page doesn't appear as a tab, so I have to right-click on the header and choose "Show as tab" to get the extension button to appear.

Comment: Maybe the issue is the access to parent document part.

Comment: I created this gist, with instructions, to show the problem: https://gist.github.com/Mottie/91968692d074f93eb9a7

Comment: `Code cannot be inserted in top-level about:-frames.` What does this part really mean?

Comment: I'm still getting this error: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access "about:blank" at origin "null". Extension must have permission to access the frame's origin, and matchAboutBlank must be true.`

Comment: @Mottie Show as tab has been removed from Chrome.