# Why chrome.tabs.executeScript matchAboutBlank is not valid for top-level about:frames?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome plugin which creates a new window based on the content of the current page, and then another plugin which needs to insert some code to the `about:blank` page created previously (using background.js, and not content_scripts, as in this case: [Chrome extension permission for "about:blank" page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288996/chrome-extension-permission-for-aboutblank-page)).

Why `chrome.tabs.executeScript` `matchAboutBlank` is not valid for top-level about:frames?
Is there any security issue about it? Any solution?

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript
>
> ```
> var executing = browser.tabs.executeScript(
>   tabId,                 // optional integer
>   details                // object
> )
> ```
>
> [detail] matchAboutBlank Optional boolean. If true, the code will be
>   injected into embedded "about:blank" and "about:srcdoc" frames if your
>   extension has access to their parent document. The code cannot be
>   inserted in top-level about: frames. Defaults to false.

Comment: Well, this feature is for a child frame only because this is the only case when the browser can find a real URL of the parent page/frame and decide if your extension can have access to the frame. They could have probably implemented it differently but it would have been much more complicated, apparently.

Comment: you can set the permission to accept *all* urls; so why not possible to accept also about:blank?

Comment: Maybe set [`match_about_blank`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match_about_blank) to the manifest can help?
I know that it's for a content scripts insertion, but maybe it will help with that problem.

Comment: Sergey, this does not work, and it is explained in the documentation. the question is why the browser limits this possibility? is it a security issue?